# Setting Outer Div to Fixed, but maintaining relative position on inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two nested divs.

```
<div style="position: fixed">
    <div style="position: relative">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I set a fixed position to the outer div, all of the elements in the inner div lose their desired positioning.  Can I maintain the order of the elements inside the inner div while still having the outer div set to a fixed position?

Comment: Tried `absolute` on the inner div?

Comment: Can you show a demo ?

Comment: this is going to be dependent on other factors. Working fine here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fJgbx

Comment: add one more div to your outer div, define `position:relative` then use `top, left right bottom property